# how to format layout in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

Hi I have a file with entry below:

```
$ cat output.csv
ajhn001
sudo --- yes
ppp --- yes
 samba_common --- no
Spectre_Meltdown --- yes

ajhg002
sudo --- yes
ppp --- yes
 samba_common --- no
 Spectre_Meltdown --- no
```

I need to make it with this format:

```
Server              Sudo        PPP         Sambacry           Specter_Meltdown
ajhn001             yes         yes         no                 yes
ajhg002             yes         yes         no                 no
```

but what my script is doing is printing below:

```
$ sh format_csv.sh
Server              Sudo        PPP         Sambacry           Specter_Meltdown
ajhn001             
sudo              yes
ppp               yes
samba_common      no
Spectre_Meltdown  yes
ajhn002             
sudo              yes
ppp               yes
samba_common      no
Spectre_Meltdown  no
```

here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
fmt="%-20s%-12s%-12s%-19s%-12s\n"
printf "$fmt" Server Sudo PPP Sambacry Specter_Meltdown

while read line
do
        #echo $line
        #echo aw
         read line1 line2 line3 line4 <<< "$line"
        printf "$fmt" "$line1" "$line3"
done < output.csv | column -t
```

Any better approach?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

fmt="%-20s%-12s%-12s%-19s%-12s\n"
printf "$fmt" Server Sudo PPP Sambacry Specter_Meltdown

awk 'NF == 1 { i=1; a[i]=$1 };
NF == 3 { i++; a[i] = $3; if (i==5) {printf "'$fmt'",a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]} };
' output.csv
```

Prints:

```
Server              Sudo        PPP         Sambacry           Specter_Meltdown
ajhn001             yes         yes         no                 yes
ajhg002             yes         yes         no                 no
```

Comment: thanks working, OT how do you remove  character ^[[1m and ^[(B^[[m , because the format is not working if it has that one on the file not sure why its being generated when I redirect the output of another script that  create the  output.csv file 
```
^[[1m samba-common --- no ^[(B^[[m
^[[1m Spectre Meltdown --- no ^[(B^[[m

Comment: That's an entirely different question/issue. I suggest you post a new question and provide details on how you generate the data where those extraneous characters appear, and provide sample data.